# Enable cross account access to all organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-organizations

I'm using AWS console, and I have a scenario where I want to grant access to an account outside of my organization to read S3 objects in all members accounts in my organization.

I was able to [enable cross account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html) between my organization's master account and the third party account, but the role applies only to the master account, and when trying to read data from a member account S3 bucket I get access denied.

How can I create a role that will be applied on all my organization?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.

All AWS permissions apply only to one Account. It is not possible to grant multi-account access.

Some other options:

- Create an **IAM Role** *in each account* and allow the external account to *assume* the roles, which will grant them permission within the target account, *or*
- Add **Bucket Policies** to *each of the target Amazon S3 buckets* that grant access to the external account